# c# Expression tree: call method with out-parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

For example: I want to call the

```cs
Int32.TryParse(String numberStr, out Int32 result)
```

in `Expression tree`, but I do not know how to get the result of parsing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special to call methods which take `out` parameters when using Expressions: just treat it as any other parameter, and the runtime takes care of it.

Here's an example of doing something like:

```
void Lambda(string input)
{
    int parsed;
    int.TryParse(input, out parsed);
    Console.WriteLine("Parsed: {0}", (object)parsed);
}
```

using expressions:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var inputParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "input");
    var parsedVar = Expression.Variable(typeof(int), "parsed");

    var tryParseCall = Expression.Call(
        typeof(int),
        "TryParse",
        null,
        inputParam,
        parsedVar); // <-- Here we pass 'parsedVar' as the 'out' parameter

    var writeLineCall = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Console),
        "WriteLine",
        null,
        Expression.Constant("Parsed: {0}"),
        Expression.Convert(parsedVar, typeof(object)));

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<string>>(
        Expression.Block(
            new[] { parsedVar },
            tryParseCall,
            writeLineCall),
        inputParam);

    var compiled = lambda.Compile();
    compiled("3");
}
```

[See it working on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DXqtob)

Answer (score -2):

The result is stored in the variable `result` (as you named in your out parameter).  Try parse attempts to parse your input, and if it succeeds, it returns `true` and puts the resulting value in the named out parameter.  Otherwise, it returns `false` and the out parameter is rendered invalid.  You would use it like so.

```
if (Int32.TryParse(String numberStr, out Int32 result)) {
    // do something with `result`
}

// something went wrong (failure state - maybe with an `else`?)
```

Comment: This does not answer with expression trees, as the question requests

Answer (score -2):

Can you please try it with **underscore** "_"

```
List<string> lstNumbs = new List<string>() {"f", "d", "7", "4", "5", "4", "2"};

var result = lstNumbs.Where(c => Int32.TryParse(c, out int _)).Select(s => s);

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GdbgIZ

Comment: This does not answer with expression trees, as the question requests